# Secure Google Cloud Storage objects between to users in a chat app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

What would be the best way to secure Google Cloud Storage objects between two users in a chat application where the users can send photos back and forth to each other? I want the objects that two users send to each other to be accessible only by them and not by other users.

I cannot use ACLs because there is a limit to how many you can have and in a chat app, there could be thousands or millions of users.

The Firebase Cloud Storage SDK security rules offer a way to set [group private](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions#group_private) access to objects to download photos, but I am not using Firebase Cloud Storage. I am using regular Google Cloud Storage. Unless there is some way for me to use Firebase Storage with my existing bucket?

Comment: "Unless there is some way for me to use Firebase Storage with my existing bucket?" See https://firebase.blog/posts/2017/03/multiplying-power-firebase-storage/#:~:text=Linking%20your%20existing%20bucket%20to,bucket%20directly%20from%20your%20app.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you know what kind of effects linking Firebase on an existing Cloud Storage bucket might have? E.g. does it write principles, etc.? And is linking Firebase to a bucket reversible in case I change my mind? I want to make sure I don't mess up an existing bucket that I am using.

Comment: Adding Firebase to a bucket doesn't change the existing permissions on the bucket. If you don't want to risk your existing bucket, you can create a separate one for use in Firebase.